# MySQL: Get the TOP 3 referrers which referrals spend the most money

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the TOP 3 referrers which referrals spend the most money. I need to get the number of referrals and the total amount the referrals have spent. Is it possible to get it done in 1 query? So far I have this query but I am not sure what I can be missing. Please help! Thank you!

```
SELECT SUM(t2.payment) as total_payments, t2.username as referral, t1.referrer as referrer
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE t1.username = t2.username  
GROUP BY referrer
ORDER BY total_payments DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

t1 (user data, about ~1000 records)

```
username   referrer 
user1       user67
user2       user89
user3       user89  
user4       user57
user5       user57
user6       user89
user7       user67
user8       user89
...
```

t2 (user payments, about ~300 records)

```
username    payment
user1        100
user1        200
user2        350
user1         50
user5        500
user1        200
user3        150
user2         80
...
```

Comment: Do you get an error? or what result you got? I guess you should left join t1 table with t2 table.

Comment: You have to GROUP BY t2.username as well.

Comment: Consider putting  providing proper DDLs and a desired result. Obviously, we don't need to see 309 rows; a dozen or so would probably do.

Comment: Please use only tags that are actually relevant to your question.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query should give you the correct result :

```
SELECT t1.referrer as referrer, count(t2.username) as referral, SUM(t2.payment) as total_payments
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE t1.username = t2.username  
GROUP BY referrer
ORDER BY total_payments DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: I have a question: Can we get also the all time total number of referrals per referrer from table "t1" with this query as well? Or we would need another query? Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you